# Jasper Report ElementGroupHeight too much space

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that has three textfields that can potentially contain lots of text. I have specified a height for each of these, wrapped them in an element group and added `textAdjust="StretchHeight"` to the textField and `positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight"` to the reportElement as below:

```
<elementGroup>
        <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="180" width="535" height="20" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}.trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="200" width="535" height="20" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}.trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="220" width="535" height="20" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field3}.trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
</elementGroup>
```

This works but there is quite a bit of whitespace at the end of each textfield. It doesn't appear to be from the content itself as I am trimming this.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The entire report (without the Mongo query) looks like:

````
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Latest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a3bcc82f-7412-423e-b109-7a84c111800f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Localhost Mongo"/>
    <subDataset name="productDetails" uuid="e21ddc86-6be3-47de-8a73-e0f836ddd976">
        <field name="product" class="java.util.List">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="features" class="java.util.List">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[features]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="interviewQuestionDetails" uuid="143b235e-1410-4d07-a21c-2757f36193f2">
        <field name="questionText" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[questionText]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="responseText" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[responseText]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="fromDate" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date(0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="formattedFromDate" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" evaluationTime="Late">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT($P{fromDate}, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="toDate" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="formattedToDate" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" evaluationTime="Late">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT($P{toDate}, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="instrument" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="instr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="subjects" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="purchaser" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orderReference" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="businessUnit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="serviceCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="field3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="questions" class="java.util.List"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="300" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="cc984ca4-2e56-47ec-aeae-ab8ae5445a37"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Object: " + $F{instr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="530" height="40" uuid="06fc31b9-564a-4b0f-ae22-5283b68d950b"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="productDetails" uuid="c5fd0b5b-723e-4216-8f9a-7dac0c38d2e4">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{subjects})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="40" width="530">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="500" height="20" uuid="d372c83e-bf42-4aa8-bbda-3841d5c069a6"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""+org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join($F{product}.toArray(),", ") + ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="500" height="20" uuid="4208d514-f41e-4b37-814d-06d797c3a088"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Features: "+org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join($F{features}.toArray(),", ") + ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="80" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c2e1d42-100d-4d1d-be01-9a089c1693ce"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Purchaser: " + $F{purchaser}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="100" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c0a0e9f-59e1-4754-b5cc-f6d469e8617d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Order Reference: " + $F{orderReference}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="120" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c0a0e9f-59e1-4754-b5cc-f6d469e8617d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Unit: " + $F{businessUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="140" width="555" height="20" uuid="1c0a0e9f-59e1-4754-b5cc-f6d469e8617d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Code: " + $F{serviceCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="160" width="555" height="20" uuid="63032d3a-0cfe-441a-bb37-5a845b2e61c7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Content:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <elementGroup>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="180" width="535" height="20" uuid="c2c03017-b519-4675-8dd0-22b1ef374aa7"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["invoice pricing structure Executive innovate Multi-lateral digital transmit South Africa Bedfordshire deposit orange Money Market Account Michigan Technician infomediaries Rand Loti Cotton salmon Frozen Arizona Tasty Rubber Keyboard Mauritius Practical Metal Chicken channels Dynamic. invoice pricing structure Executive innovate Multi-lateral digital transmit South Africa Bedfordshire deposit orange Money Market Account Michigan Technician infomediaries Rand Loti Cotton salmon Frozen Arizona Tasty Rubber Keyboard Mauritius Practical Metal Chicken channels Dynamic. invoice pricing structure Executive innovate Multi-lateral digital transmit South Africa Bedfordshire deposit orange Money Market Account Michigan Technician infomediaries Rand Loti Cotton salmon Frozen Arizona Tasty Rubber Keyboard Mauritius Practical Metal Chicken channels Dynamic"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="200" width="535" height="20" uuid="85d8213d-ea25-40c8-9d0c-07d289aaf716"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="220" width="535" height="20" uuid="d2d98193-506a-418e-a66f-756402c75825"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </elementGroup>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="240" width="555" height="20" uuid="63032d3a-0cfe-441a-bb37-5a845b2e61c7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Interview Questions]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="260" width="530" height="40" uuid="06fc31b9-564a-4b0f-ae22-5283b68d950b"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="interviewQuestionDetails" uuid="a66a2c1a-bba0-4858-b3ed-ee25a9bd28a1">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{questions})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="40" width="530">
                        <elementGroup>
                            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="0" width="500" height="20" uuid="4b6eccd1-2234-40c3-ac88-256f621b784d"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{questionText}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="20" y="20" width="500" height="20" uuid="d74141e1-fef5-4b7f-85af-ccd041fe1162"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{responseText}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </elementGroup>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW9tb.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `stretchType="ElementGroupHeight"` for the text elements (or use an element group).

If you want a text element to stretch to accommodate its content, setting `textAdjust="StretchHeight"` is enough.

The `stretchType` attribute is used to stretch elements based on how other elements or containers stretch.  You can read some details [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#reportElement) and [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/stretch/index.html#stretch).

Comment: That's great thank you. Should I just use padding bottom to the textfields with the dynamic content to better space them out? You suggestion has gotten rid of the unnecessary space but they are a bit bunched up.

Comment: Yes, you can either set a bottom padding for the texts or leave some empty space between the elements.